# Difference between declaration statement and assignment statement in C?

Tags: c, difference

I am new to programming and trying to learn C. I am reading a book where I read about these statements but could not understand their meaning.

Answer (score 14):

Declaration:

```
int a;
```

Assignment:

```
a = 3;
```

Declaration and assignment in one statement:

```
int a = 3;
```

Declaration says, "I'm going to use a variable named "`a`" to store an integer value." Assignment says, "Put the value 3 into the variable `a`."

(As @delnan points out, my last example is technically *initialization*, since you're specifying what value the variable starts with, rather than changing the value. Initialization has special syntax that also supports specifying the contents of a struct or array.)

Comment: The third isn't an assignment. It's initalization.

Comment: It matters in C insofar you can do things in initialization that you can't do in assignment. For example `int a[2] = {};` works but `int a[2]; a = {};` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable sets it up to be used at a later point in the code. You can create variables to hold numbers, characters, strings (an array of characters), etc.

You can declare a variable without giving it a value. But, until a variable has a value, it's not very useful.

You declare a variable like so: `char myChar;` NOTE: This variable is not initialized.

Once a variable is declared, you can assign a value to it, like: `myChar = 'a';` NOTE: Assigning a value to `myChar` initializes the variable.

To make things easier, if you know what a variable should be when you declare it, you can simply declare it and assign it a value in one statement: `char myChar = 'a';` NOTE: This declares and initializes the variable.

So, once your myChar variable has been given a value, you can then use it in your code elsewhere. Example:

```
char myChar = 'a';
char myOtherChar = 'b';
printf("myChar: %c\nmyOtherChar: %c", myChar, myOtherChar);
```

This prints the value of myChar and myOtherChar to stdout (the console), and looks like:

```
myChar: a
myOtherChar: b
```

If you had declared `char myChar;` without assigning it a value, and then attempted to print `myChar` to stdout, you would receive an error telling you that myChar has not been initialized.

Comment: You mostly describe the difference between declaring a variable and not initializing it vs. declaring a variable and initializing it.