# Variables assignment

Tags: c++, algorithm, variables

I have a question for an exam and by the way that it sounds, it could be a trap question:

> How many assignments will there be executed in the following algorithm if `n` and `p` are considered to be ***integers***?

```
p=1;
n=279;

while (n>=100) { 
  p=p*10;
  n=n-100;
}
```

I would say that there are 4 assignments in the while loop and two before the while ... so 6 ? I'm not sure why the question highlights the integer feature of the variables.

Comment: Knowing they're integers, you know they can go negative by subtraction. Unsigned integers couldn't.

Comment: Wasn't trying to answer the question, just accounting for the significance
of *integer*. If `n` was *unsigned* it would loop forever. Since the
code is C-like but not compilable C, I don't know whether to count `p=1; n=279;` as *assignments* or *initializations*. Sloppy question IMO. If it's
not multiple choice you might say "It depends..." and explain both ways.

Comment: Sloppy question IMO also. That's why i have the doubt about how many would there be ... But which would be the difference between a initialization (i asume it's the operation through which a value is assigned to the variable) and asignment ? is assignment considered the situation when the same variable will get through another operation a new value ?

Comment: Correct. Initialization = variable created with value. Assignment = old variable assumes new value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say 6 because the declaration seems to be somewhere else -- it's not

```
int p=1, n=279;
```

Ok, even in that case I'd lean towards 6 because the declarations imply assignments (and this thread seems to agree: [Difference between declaration statement and assignment statement in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23227486/difference-between-declaration-statement-and-assignment-statement-in-c) ), but this is fortunately not the question here.